# For and While Loop to extract a portion of a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, arcgis

I am having issues extracting numbers from a string to create a new field using field calculator in ArcGIS. The values being extracted have to remain as a string. The issue that I am having is that there is no consistency in the number of characters leading up to and following the numbers I wish to extract. The only consistency there is within the string is a comma that follows the desired number.

So far my code is as follows:

```
def get_num_from_string(string):  
    num = '' 
    for i in string:  
        if i in '1234567890':  
            num+=i 
    return num
```

This code is unsuccessful in accomplishing my goal I need the code to step through each character in the string and return only numbers until the comma is reached. For example if the original string is "River Lot 489, 11756 MB CODE" I want my output string to read "489".

Comment: What precisely does *"numbers which follow my desired ones, giving me incorrect values"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think a while loop would be more suited to iterate over a finite length of characters in a string

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner Python user so pardon my naivety. What I mean @jonrsharpe is there are numbers in the data that come after the numbers I am trying to extract from the original.

For example:
"River Lot 489, 127756 MB CODE"
I want my output to simply be
"489"

Comment: That's not really a beginning Python problem, the question is unclear. **Give some examples**.

Comment: For example: "River Lot 489, 127756 MB CODE" I want my output to simply be "489" @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have the String

```
>>> test = "12hel34l0"
```

To get all the digits in the String, simply do

```
>>> print([d for d in test if d.isdigit()])
['1', '2', '3', '4', '0']
```

If you want it to be a String again instead of a list, use `join`

```
>>> print(''.join([d for d in test if d.isdigit()]))
12340
```

**Edit**:

> "River Lot 489, 127756 MB CODE" I want my output to simply be "489"

To match this, I simply change the following method to `test.split(",")[0]`. You have to provide more information how your data looks like and if you want to get the digits before the *first comma every time*.

Implemented in your method.

```
def get_num_from_string(string):
    return ''.join([d for d in test.split(",")[0] if d.isdigit()])
```

Testing your provided example

```
>>> test = "River Lot 489, 127756 MB CODE"
>>> print(get_num_from_string(test))
489
```